# Query Facebook page permissions granted by user to FB app with JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-apps

I would like to know, how can I access the permissions specific to a FB page that was given by the user through a FB app.

My problem is, that I want to create a messaging service, which requires the user to give permission to:

- manage_pages
- pages_messaging
- pages_messaging_subscriptions

The user authenticate into my system, I ask these permission. The user has the options to choose which pages he wants to give these permissions, and he can make the mistake of clicking on the wrong page in one category. Because of this, my service will not work properly.

For example:

- I have two pages, named: A, B
- I give manage_pages permission to A, but not B.
- I want to give pages_messaging and pages_messaging_subscription to A, however I missclick, and give it to B.
- My service will not work properly after this.

So, I need to check for the given permissions for page A. How can I do that?

This project is written in Vue, so basically I am using the JavaScript SDK to do this.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling

Comment: @CBroe this link did not help. This returns the scope I asked for, however not the actually granted permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like this solution, but I cannot find any other way to do it

1. GET me/accounts?access_token={user-access-token}

returns array of pages with Page Tokens as `access_token`

2. GET /debug_token?input_token={page-access-token}&access_token={app-id|app-secret}

returns object with `scopes` granted application scopes for page

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling)